# Tooltip not showing on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap tooltip is only showing on focus, not hover. The tooltip does correctly show on the right side. Using Bootstrap 2.3.1. Using `data-trigger='focus'` on the `<span>` does not have any effect either. Works for me in Firefox. Does not work in Chrome 27. Works in Chrome 28 (Canary).

Full HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <span class='qinfo' title="Message 1">(?)</span>
            <span class='qinfo' title="Message 2">(?)</span>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('.qinfo').tooltip({'placement':'right','trigger':'hover'});
```

Comment: That's strange. I put it in a fiddle and works as expected. http://fiddle.jshell.net/dQnwU/
Do you have some more code that is hooked to the span?

Comment: @Yeronimo This is [tag:twitter-bootstrap], not jQuery UI.

Comment: It is working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/aU3DP/
It is something else, maybe the span container is causing the issue.

Comment: **Actually** using Twitter Bootstrap, here's a fiddle demonstrating it works fine when you hover: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9hBDF/

Comment: @gustavodidomenico How does that work for you? You didn't include any tooltip library, and if you look at the console, there's an error because of it.

Comment: Let me try to replicate the problem in the fiddle. Thanks

Comment: @gustavodidomenico What we see in your fiddle is the tooltip printed by the browser with the title tag of your html code, not the bootstrap tooltip.

Comment: I pulled out everything from my HTML except for the span, and still have the issue. I copied the Bootstrap CSS/JS from the fiddle links as well, with no change.

Comment: @Mooseman Are you referring to a fiddle not working or your website? My fiddle works for me on FF 20, IE 9, and Chrome 26. Why are you mixing the triggers? You said you want it to be for "hover", but you set the `data-trigger` attribute as "focus". You understand that the "focus" `trigger` doesn't work for non-input elements, right? You could use "click", not "focus" though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that only occurs in Chrome 27. Since there are no problems in other versions of Chrome, and there are no problems in other browsers using `$('.qinfo').tooltip({'placement':'right','trigger':'hover'});`.  There's not much to do about it.

Answer (score -1):

The option trigger is default hover and focus, so you don't have to set that one.